# Set Identity Insert On With DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I am using entity framework dbcontext
I am trying to set/reset identity_insert from my code for my 'primaryIdField' but entity framework somehow neglect the command SET IDENTITY_INSERT Database.dbo.mytable ON and inserts new column in the database with primaryIdField = max(id) in database + 1,

What I have done is

```
using (var context =    DbManager.GetEntityContext(myConnectionString).MyContext)
    {
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
            {
                context.Database.Connection.Open();
                context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Database.dbo.mytable ON");

                context.Set<MyModel>().Add(myModel);
                context.SaveChanges();
                context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Database.dbo.mytable OFF");
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way?  Wouldn't letting the SQL server insert the next ID be more appropriate?  Generally you only use Identity Insert in cases where you want to duplicate rows from another database, preserving the original primary key.  In this case it appears you are just adding a new record; in which case you should let SQL handle the new key value for the row. Set your primary key field using the Indentiy specification property in the designer or 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, ....' If Oracle you need a trigger.

Comment: @TechneWare: I think there are (some) use-cases where this procedure is perfectly valid - even if I'd mainly use this for bulk inserts

Answer (score 2):

For your actual problem: by default EF will prevent you from assigning the primary key of an entity by hand (by not sending the value in the query). If you want to tell EF that you want to do exactly that you will have to add the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` attribute to your entity's Key declaration:

```
public class MyEntity 
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Key { get; set; }
}
```

Some side-notes:

1. I believe you don't have to do anything fancy with the connection by hand (but I may be wrong).
2. If you are using EF6 you should use `context.Database.BeginTransaction()` to open the transaction. It's the recommended way of doing so: [MSDN / Working with Transactions (EF6 Onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx)
3. I don't think it'll make a huge difference, but you probably should use `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` instead of `context.Database.SqlQuery<T>()`.